# Solr Boosting failed

Tags: boost, solr, edismax

We have following fields that should be prioritized in the search results as below

Name (Priority 1)
Code (Priority 2)
Description (Priority 3)
Short description (Priority 4)

Boost query we applied:

```
bq=(Name)^50&bq=(Code)^40&bq=(Description)^30&bq=(Short description)^20
```

**Issue Description:**

Boosting is not working as Priority3 items comes to top than Priority2.

**Search results output:**

***Name (Priority 1)***

***Description (Priority 3)***

***Code (Priority 2)***

***Short description (Priority 4)***

**What we have done to fix the issue:**

We applied constant score (^=) and also tried to give high score for code (P2) than Description (P3), but that also not giving expected results.

**What we need:**

Search results should be ordered based on priority specified as per boosting value.

Please advise.

Comment: You might need to tweak the boost factors. I would start by adding `debug=true` to the query and looking at how the documents where scored (look for `debug/explain' in the result)

Comment: Thanks Hector. I used "tie" parameters to improve the results.However have to enable the debug to identify score few fields which are not prioritized as per boosting.. Also, have seen the debug enabled results are not easy to read. Is there better way to make it simple and readable.

Comment: Indeed, the "explain" information is hard to read. It's full of good information but hard to read. I blogged about some of this here: https://library.brown.edu/create/digitaltechnologies/understanding-scoring-of-documents-in-solr/ I hope it helps a bit.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you use bq :

```
/select?q=*:*&bq=name:*^100&bq=code:*^100&defType=edismax&fl=score,*
```

you apply 'new query' to be boosted.

This is how you use bf :

```
/select?defType=edismax&fl=score,*&q=*:*&bf=numeric_field^1.5
```

you can read more in [solr query parser](https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_4/the-dismax-query-parser.html) on how to use/limitation of bf/bq